# How to bind UniformGrid to datasource with (x,y) coordinates, and fill missing elements with another UserControl?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, itemscontrol

I need a uniform grid of controls in order to, say, model a chess plate with different pieces on it. I have a List of ChessPiece as datasource, and each piece has a coordinate (x,y).

I thought about binding this datasource to a UniformGrid control, so that:

1. each piece shows at the correct coordinates
2. empty coordinates are filled with another control (e.g., a button, that could trigger some event when pressed).

I found [this article](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-itemscontrol-example/) which works pretty well to solve point i). However, I don't know how to fill the empty coordinates, i.e., to solve point ii) without *messing* with the datasource list.

Is there any elegant solution?

Thank you.